# Why print object display prototype chain not as expected

Tags: javascript

```
function F () {
   this.a = 1;
   this.b = 2;
}
let o = new F(); // {a: 1, b: 2}

// add properties in F function's prototype
F.prototype.b = 3;
F.prototype.c = 4;
console.log(o)
```

Using Chrome's developer tools, I find the output as follows:

[image]

I'm really confused with this output.
Who can explain the result.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am not entirely sure about this answer.*

`__proto__` refers to the **object** that is being constructed (it's part of the constructor).

`[[Prototype]]` is the object that is meant to **prototype** the **current** object.

Answer (score 1):

`[[Prototype]]` refers to the internal prototype that every object is created with. It is not accessible, for example

```
o.prototype.b
```

returns `undefined`.

The deprecated `__proto__` is initially uncalled, and, when it is called, fills up with the values of `[[Prototype]]`, hence the duplication. So,

```
o.__proto__.b
```

returns `3`.

The [preferred access method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is to use the `getPrototypeOf()` static method of `Object`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(o).b
```

returns `3`.